# problem with WP-Post Ratings meta content

Tags: plugin-wp-postratings

i use WP-Post Ratings for my site and all thing are good but i have only one major problem with this plugin.

i use easy digital downloads plugin too. and I'm disable the default post type of this plugin because i want to use single.php for sell products.and also i use the blew code in the single.php file to show Ratings.

`<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>`

but in the HTML source of the Ratings in the post there is a problem.

see blew meta content:

`<meta content="http://rokesh.ir/downloads/pinblack/" itemprop="url">`

in this meta content you see the URL of the easy digital downloads plugin but i want to see the URL of the post plugin like this:

`<meta content="http://rokesh.ir/wordpress-portfolio-theme-pinblack/" itemprop="url">`

[you can see check it online here](http://rokesh.ir/wordpress-portfolio-theme-pinblack/)

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/

Comment: It seems you didn't disable the Easy Digital Downloads plugin if it is still affecting the URL. I don't see how WP-PostRatings is involved in the problem. Could you explain the problem very carefully?

Comment: I ask from edd developers too .And they give me some information's. but because i don't know programing i cant solve it. please read this topic and help me. https://easydigitaldownloads.com/support/topic/problem-with-wp-post-ratings-meta-content-plugin/